# How to add doc2pdf to custom docker container

Tags: python, docker, docx2pdf

I want to use `doc2pdf` program in my `python:3.9-slim-bullseye` container

I added `libreoffice-writer unoconv` to my container

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /project
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONBUFFERED=1

COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    libreoffice-writer unoconv \
    gcc libc-dev libpq-dev  python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python3-lxml && apt-get install -y cron &&\
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Then I logged in my container and received error below

```
docker-exec -ti <Container_NAME> bash

root@cfdbb27947c6:/project/documents_app/templates# doc2pdf doc_1.docx 
unoconv: Cannot find a suitable pyuno library and python binary combination in /usr/lib/libreoffice
ERROR: No module named 'uno'

unoconv: Cannot find a suitable office installation on your system.
ERROR: Please locate your office installation and send your feedback to:
       http://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues
root@cfdbb27947c6:/project/documents_app/templates#
```

How can i fix the error?

UPDATE 1
Was trying to install  `python3-uno` but it didn't help

Also added this

```
uno==0.3.3
base==1.0.4
unotools
```

but still have errors

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's|#!/usr/bin/env python3|#!/usr/bin/python3|' /usr/bin/unoconv
```

Found this solution under the following link: https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues/49

Comment: Thank you,
could you please explain how can I add this to my docker?