# Issue with unoconv in PHP with a laragon server

Tags: php, laragon, unoconv

I have an issue with running `unoconv` from my laragon PHP server.

Info:
It's a somewhat older project that uses `unoconv` to convert docx files to pdf files. Which has worked fine for a long time in my setup. I recently switched from the thread-safe version of PHP to the non thread-safe version of PHP 7.4.32. I copied over the entire php.ini so it should be the same in that area.

When I check the phpinfo  I can see that the PATH is the same for both the thread-safe version and the NTS version. Both `unoconv` and the office installation is in the path.

This is the command I'm running right now:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:/unoconv/unoconv.py C:/laragon/www/vak/storage/documents/doc.148.docx 2>&1
```

Like I said this works fine in the thread-safe version but not in the NTS version.

The error I'm getting is this:

> unoconv: Cannot find a suitable office installation on your system.
> ERROR: Please locate your office installation and send your feedback to:
> http://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues

I am completely lost here. thanks in advance

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with PHP, because you are executing Python scripts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add doc2pdf to custom docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72746661/how-to-add-doc2pdf-to-custom-docker-container)

Comment: The command works in shell/CLI but fails in `exec` or `shell_exec`? Please add details of how PHP relates.

Comment: Yes it works if I run it directly in the command line. The issue is that it doesn't work when running it from the apache server.
it fails with both exec and shell_exec.
I think it has something to do with permissions but I can not figure out what.
It also works fine if I run the php file through the command line. It's just when running through the server

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry I forgot to tag you

Comment: @DylanBos Apache is running as the same user you are running the CLI as?

Comment: @user3783243 it should be, why would that be different depending on the various versions of PHP I'm using? 
When using 7.4.32 TS version it works, but with 7.4.32 NTS it does not. IT's the same server just a different version.

Comment: @user3783243 I just checked with the command `echo exec('whoami');` and it shows me my default windows user (I only have 1 aside from administrator). So that shouldn't be the issue, right?